# JAX-WS Schema http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd not able to be found

Tags: java, web-services, spring, jax-ws

I am implementing JAX-WS with Spring framework.

The following is my Spring applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core"
xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core
    http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core.xsd
    http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet
    http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    ">
```

However, Eclipse is complaining:

> Referenced file contains errors (http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd).

After investigation, I find the URL:
http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd
Does not exist.
Instead, it seems be move to:
http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd
(You can open this link in the brower)

Therefore, I updated XSD schema URL from 
http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd
to
http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd

Now my applicationContext.xml looks like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core"
xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core
    http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/core.xsd
    http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet
    http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    ">
```

Actually with this change the Eclipse error goes away.
The problem is after launching the web service in Tomcat 7, I get the following runtime error instead:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 20; columnNumber: 29; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.warning(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:99)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:433)

Please advise.

Thank you very much.
Regards,

Comment: you ahould really strive to use local schemas in production applications, otherwise your application is at the mercy of these unrelated, third-party webservers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that you change the location from http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd to http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd. Even though the latter one is the right url, it does not match what is defined in your jaxws-spring.jar META-INF/spring.schema file. That file should have the following content

```
http\://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core.xsd=spring-jax-ws-core.xsd
http\://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd=spring-jax-ws-servlet.xsd
http\://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/local-transport.xsd=spring-jax-ws-local-transport.xsd
```

Spring uses this mapping to search the schema in the classpath rather than to internet. Those schema files are located at the root of the jaxws-spring.jar file.

Please take a look [Registering the handler and the schema](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/extensible-xml.html#extensible-xml-registration)

Answer (score 1):

are you using spring in your project?, I had the same problem, but when I included spring-jaxws in my maven dependencies the problem solved, in fact, yo can see in that jar that the META-INF/spring.schemas file is redefining the XSDs locations

Answer (score 1):

Resources have moved, final config should be:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans        
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
        http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core 
        http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/core.xsd
        http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet 
        http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd"
        default-lazy-init="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not a case with yours. But in such a scenario, do clean and make a fresh build. Reason being the older spring jar and xsd from there would be taken if the two jars exits. Hope that helps for other guys .... generically this exception will be thrown for many reasons.