# Trying to bind a simple webservice using JAXWS to the Spring bean and there is an error of XSD reading in my application context xml

Tags: spring, xsd, jax-ws, wss, websphere-liberty

I am trying to bind already functional JAXWS web service deployed on IBM WAS Liberty 8.5.5.4 using JDK 1.7 but getting following error when binding the service as per applicationContext.xml. It is a simple web application with nothing other than web service, spring version is 4.1.0

> schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not `<xsd:schema>`.
>
> [ERROR   ] Context initialization failed
>   Line 30 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/META-INF/applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 30; columnNumber: 30; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'wss:binding'.
>
> [ERROR   ] SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 30 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/META-INF/applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 30; columnNumber: 30; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'wss:binding'.
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
>
> ***Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 30; columnNumber: 30; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'wss:binding'.
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)***

I searched existing issues and found same exception in an issue active a year ago [old issue link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16007940/spring-application-context-xsd-schema-read-issue) . As per the solution I have

1. jaxws-rt.jar version 2.2.7 in the classpath - the applicationContext.xml does find it and resolves the binding tag at compile time but gives problem at runtime
2. I have updated the xsd location as mentioned in the issue and also verified that xsd does exist at http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd

Below is applicationContext.xml contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core"
xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"    

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/core.xsd 
http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd">

<bean id="viewResolver"class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="cache" value="false" />
<property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
```

```
<bean id="mathService" class="com.adp.sbs.jaxws.service.MathServiceImpl" />

<wss:binding url="/math">
<wss:service>
    <ws:service bean="#mathService" />
</wss:service>
```

```
</beans>
```

Any ideas why do I still get the exception?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems on WAS 6, WAS couldn't find resources located in other Jars. In my case, it couldn't find the spring-namespacehandlers (located in META-INF/spring...) of spring-integration, but spring itself  worked. So my problem was similar to yours :)

I turned my WAS to debug level for all spring classes, which caused really long output. But i could find out, that no BeanConfigurator can't find the handler files to handle the spring-integration-xsd.

**But what does spring do to start your application context? (background information)**

The basic spring.jar does not contain all parsers to create contextes. It is checking for context-definitions (e.g. xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core") and tries to find a resolver for it. Therefore it is checking all jars if they contain /META-INF/spring.handler and META-INF/spring.schemas. 
The spring.handler contains the path to an implementation of the [NamespaceHandler](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-beans/4.1.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/NamespaceHandler.java#NamespaceHandler) interface. Those class is responsible to redirect to the specific AbstractBeanDefinitionParser. The other class contains aliases for xsd-names.

I can think of 2 possible solutions without knowing more about your application:

First, jax-ws does not contain those spring.handler file, plus the necessary implementation of the namespaceHandler. So you would need a third-party jax-ws-spring.jar, which contains those classes. 
I can't tell if this would match your problem, because you didn't append your dependencies.

Second solution would be to extract the files (spring.handler, or the xsd) from the jar and add them to your application. Luckily, you don't need to do that manually after each build, there is a maven plugin.

```
<plugin>

  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>extract-jaxws-stuff</id>
      <phase>generate-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>unpack</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <artifactItems>
          <artifactItem>
            <groupId>jax-ws-groupid</groupId>
            <artifactId>jax-ws-artifactId</artifactId>
            <version>${jax-ws.version}</version>
            <outputDirectory>src/main/resources</outputDirectory>
            <includes>path/to/the/resource</includes>
          </artifactItem>
        </artifactItems>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

**Update:**

Open your jaxws-spring.jar and find the spring.handlers and spring.schemas files in the META-INF folder. Copy the files in your applications META-INF folder.
If this didn't work too: 
Merge the spring.handlers and spring.schemas files with the exisiting files in your spring-context.jar.

Good luck, or give feedback to find other problems.

Comment: I had the jaxws-spring-1.8.jar and tried upgrading to jaxws-spring-1.9.jar as well which has the XSD's but still got the same error. I am using eclipse websphere liberty developer tools to deploy the EAR. I was deploying the jar in WEB-INF/lib and tried extracting out the jar but still same error.    Is the schemaLocation correct                        http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core.xsd=spring-jax-ws-core.xsd 
    http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd=spring-jax-ws-servlet.xsd">

Comment: Ok, so probably spring finds the xsd, but can't find the spring.* files, i've added an update to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Martin!!!  I copied the files as you suggested and had to get latest jaxws-ri, now I am much ahead with no exceptions but still somehow <wss:binding url="/math"> is not working. When I try to access it http://localhost:9080/LibWSTestWeb/math?WSDL get no file found

Comment: Updated a bit soon. My bad I didnt have the entry WSSpringServlet in the web.xml thought I had it but IT'S WORKING NOW... Thanks for all your help!!!

Comment: You're welcome, but which files did you copy now? What was your exact solution? Probably we should update/validate/accept my answer to make it useful for other people facing the same problem?

Comment: I opened the jaxws-spring.jar and copied the spring.handlers, spring.schemas and *.xsd into META-INF folder. After that got exceptions indicating different classes missing at various point, so I got latest jaxb-ri-2.2.11.zip and added all the *.jar files from the zip into my WEB_INF/lib folder of my ear. After that all worked fine!!! I am a new member of stackoverflow and unfortunately I cannot vote till I have 15 points I guess...