# Failed to read schema document 'http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jax-ws, spring-ws

[http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd'](http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd%27).
- schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/
servlet.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root
element of the document is not xsd:schema.

Tried following multiple URLs but still same error , please help to resolve
[JAX-WS Schema http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd not able to be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741729/jax-ws-schema-http-jax-ws-dev-java-net-spring-servlet-xsd-not-able-to-be-found)
[Spring 'application-context' XSD schema read issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16007940/spring-application-context-xsd-schema-read-issue)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core"
       xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core      
       http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/core.xsd   - Error
        http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet
        http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd ">  _ Error

  <wss:binding url="/customer">  - error on this tag
        <wss:service>
            <ws:service bean="#customerEndpoint" />
        </wss:service>
    </wss:binding>
```

POM.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.stream.buffer/streambuffer -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.stream.buffer</groupId>
    <artifactId>streambuffer</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```